# How do I prevent Gradle from building a non-project directory?

Tags: gradle

In the Gradle samples (included with version 2.2.1) there is a java/multiproject project.

The `settings.gradle` file defines the following projects:

> include "shared", "api", "services:webservice", "services:shared"

Note that `services` is **not** itself a project, merely a directory which *contains* the `webservice` and `shared` projects.

When I run the command `gradle build` from the root directory, I notice that after gradle successfully builds it creates inside the `/services` directory a `/build` directory containing `/lib` and a `/tmp` directories.

Inside of `/services/build/lib` is a jar: `services-1.0.jar` which contains very little; specifically just a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file containing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
provider: gradle
```

So what is causing Gradle to build a jar for this non-project?  And how can I prevent this behavior in my similarly structured multiproject project?

`/services` isn't a project, I don't want to create anything inside `/build` folder at all.  Yes I could just delete it, but I would like to avoid the unnecessary work of building this jar/running any tasks on this non-project in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest I've no reasonable idea why gradle builds this *folder*. I guess that because it's a kind of a `transient` folder. However it can be excluded by adding the following piece of code to main `build.gradle` script:

```
project(':services').jar { onlyIf { false } }
```

Desired effect (`services.jar` elimination) can be also obtained with the following `settings.gradle` content:

```
include "shared", "api", "services/webservice", "services/shared"
```

*File* instead of *project* paths are included.

Comment: This will avoid the jar-ing, but isn't Gradle still running the other java plugin tasks here?  It's checking to compile classes and such, there just happen to be no class files.  I'd like to avoid that check entirely.

Comment: @TomTresansky have You seen my updated answer, does it solve the problem?

Comment: Just noticed it now.  Will try later tonight.

Comment: Works brilliantly!  No more useless artifacts produced, and running gradle projects no longer shows the false :services project.  Had to update everywhere else (in my project) which named the subprojects to use the notation :folder/subproject, such as the project dependencies, and problem solved.  Thanks!

Comment: The trick with replacing `:` with `/` doesn't work for me. It print error `The project name 'services/webservice' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |].` Gradle version 6.3.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that this is a combination of the next 2 gradle rules:

1. When you're including subprojects in the build.settings file using the `include` keyword according to Gradle Documentation [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html):

   > the inclusion of the path 'services:hotels:api' will result in
   >   creating 3 projects: 'services', 'services:hotels' and
   >   'services:hotels:api'.

   In simple words, this means that the inclusion of services::webservice will also build the services project
2. The bulid.gradle file in your root that applies the 'java' plugin. According to Gradle Documentation [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#sec:examples) every configuration defined in the root.gradle takes effect for all sub projects. This means that it will also hold as the default configuration for the services project. As the 'java' plugin was applied a jar will be created, but as there is no src/main folder under the services directory nothing will be compiled and the jar will include only a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: While the first rules is 100% reasonable I will doubt if the second one does make sense because `service` is not defined as a subproject explicitly - it's *transitive* in some way. Got my upvote :)

Comment: Alright, so that explains the why, and you've got my upvote for it.  Any idea how to explicitly say `/services` isn't a project, so ignore it?  Is this even possible?

Comment: No a built in keyword that I'm aware of. You can, however, overwrite a task so the behavior (

Comment: No a built in keyword that I'm aware of. You can, however, overwrite a java task so a behavior previously defined by will be replaced. In this specific case, overriding the java plugin 'assemble' task by adding the following line to the build.gradle in the services folder will do the job:
    'task assemble(overwrite: true) << { }'
You can read more about overwriting tasks in https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10EF0

Comment: @AmnonShochot, we have worked it out. See the updated answer.